# Sitecore 6.x /sitecore/login Parser Error

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, sitecore

I found out one interesting issue with sitecore admin page 
if my setting in web conашп target to 4.5 framework is next

```
>  compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"
> enablePrefetchOptimization="true"
```

Iam gettting  next error:

```
Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: The base class includes the field 'StartPage', but its type (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl) is not compatible with the type of control (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlIframe).

Source Error: 


Line 71:             </div>
Line 72:             <div id="SDN">
Line 73:                 <iframe id="StartPage" runat="server" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"
Line 74:                     marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" style="display: none"></iframe>
Line 75:             </div>
```

if targetFramework arrrib  is 4.0 all working fine.
How to fix it ? 
My goal is work in full 4.5 FW mode,
I had set up additionally

```
<httpRuntime 
encoderType="System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder,System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"   
maxRequestLength="512000" 
executionTimeout="600" 
enableKernelOutputCache="false" 
targetFramework="4.5" 
requestValidationMode="4.0"/>
```

and `<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>`

Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I foundout the solution, I need just customize log in page.

Comment: Which is? I've seen this solution mentioned a few times: http://www.mikkelhm.dk/post/2012/08/25/Tip-of-the-week-Week-33-Sitecore-and-NET-45.aspx

Comment: @Cleric, How did you fix this problem?

Comment: I created a custom login page (based on real sitecore login page)

Comment: Please include a detailed solution in your answer so that others can use it.

Answer (score 5):

Found a super simple solution to this in Sitecore 6.6.  Just rename the iFrame to div!

```
      <div id="SDN">
            <div id="StartPage" runat="server" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"
                marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" style="display: none"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Did you find any other problems with this solution? Did it break anything else?

Comment: Works in 6.4.1 as well (I have to support it still unfortunately even though we've moved to 7.5+ for most projects). This particular error is only caused by the stupid information box on the login page, so changing this tiny bit of code isn't going to break anything. As for the rest of Sitecore running fine in framework 4.5 I've not been able to extensively test it but it seems to run fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your target framework must be 4.0 in order for Sitecore to work properly. 
Version 4.5 is not yet supported

Comment: Is this still the case with 6.6?

Answer (score 2):

First you'll need to find and edit the file default.aspx in Website\sitecore\login.

Change this:

```
<div id="SDN">
    <iframe id="StartPage" runat="server" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"
                marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" style="display: none"></iframe>
</div>
```

to this:

```
<div id="SDN">
    <div id="StartPage>   </div>
</div>
```

Save this file.

The iframe displays browser compabitibilty information from sitecore on the right side of the login page.

What happens is that when you use .NET 4.5, the iframe compiles to an HtmlIframe control. The code behind file from sitecore however has the iframe as an HtmlGeneric control. Hence the message.

By changing the iframe to a div, ASP.NET will generate an HtmlGeneric from the .aspx page which matches what is in the compiled code behind and the login page is then able to load.

Comment: This doesn't work in 6.4.1 in case anyone is trying this. You need `runat="server"` on the `div`

Answer (score 0):

I got same error and added "targetFrameowkr=4.5.1" in complication entry in web.config file and issues fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem and i have changed the target framework from 4.0 to 4.5 in web.config file.